# How to display image slices preloaded in two dimensional array instead of placeholders?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to assemble and display image slices which have been preloaded into a two dimensional array, but the code is only showing placeholders instead of the images.

The image slices have been preloaded with a javascript function, but when I use a second javascript function to retrieve and assemble the image slices I'm just getting placeholders instead of the images. The first javascript function to preload the image slices is called at the bottom of the head section in the HTML page and uses a query string to retrieve part of the image file name (queryData[2]), the second javascript function to assemble the images is in the body tag and called as onload=assembleImage();. I've used console.log in both functions which have shown the image slices are present. Is there a reason why I'm only getting placeholders instead of images? My code is below.

```
// First function to preload image slices into a two dimensional array.


function preloadImages(){

    preloadImages = [];
    var row = 5;
    var col = 5;

    for (var r = 0; r < row; r++){
        preloadImages[r] = new Image();
        for (var c = 0; c < col; c++){
            preloadImages[r][c] = new Image();
            preloadImages[r][c].src = queryData[2] + "_" + (r) + "_" + (c) + ".jpg";    
        }
    }
    //console.log(preloadImages[r][c]);
}

// Second function to retrieve and assemble image slices.

function assembleImage(){   

    var row = 5;
    var col = 5;
    var assembleImage = document.getElementById("prodImage");
    var imageTable = "<table>";

    for (var r = 0; r < row; r++){
        imageTable += "<tr>";
            for (var c = 0; c < col; c++){
                imageTable += "<td>";
                imageTable += "<img src = " + preloadImages[r][c].src + "/>";
                imageTable += "</td>";

            console.log(preloadImages[r][c])
            }
        imageTable += "</tr>";
    }
    imageTable += "</table>";
    assembleImage.innerHTML = imageTable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the main issues you are hitting, is assigning `preloadImages[r]` to a `new Image()`, rather than an `Array`. Also, you define `preloadImages` as a function and a variable (implicit global) to use for your two-dimensional `Array`. After renaming those variables and doing a bit of cleanup, your code runs fine, as seen below:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    var queryData = [
        'https://makelin.us/100/100',
        'https://makelin.us/100/100',
        'https://makelin.us/100/100'
    ];
    var preloadImages = [];
    // First function to preload image slices into a two dimensional array.
    function preloadAllImages() {
        var row = 5;
        var col = 5;

        for (var r = 0; r < row; r++) {
            preloadImages[r] = [];
            for (var c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                preloadImages[r][c] = new Image();
                preloadImages[r][c].src = queryData[2];
            }
        }
        // console.log(preloadImages);
    }
    preloadAllImages();

    // Second function to retrieve and assemble image slices.
    function assembleImage() {
        var row = 5;
        var col = 5;
        var assembleImage = document.getElementById("prodImage");
        var imageTable = "<table>";

        for (var r = 0; r < row; r++) {
            imageTable += "<tr>";
            for (var c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                imageTable += "<td>";
                imageTable += "<img src=" + preloadImages[r][c].src + "/>";
                imageTable += "</td>";

                // console.log(preloadImages[r][c])
            }
            imageTable += "</tr>";
        }
        imageTable += "</table>";
        // console.log(imageTable);
        assembleImage.innerHTML = imageTable;
        // console.log(assembleImage);
    }
    assembleImage();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>repl.it</title>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
 <div id="prodImage"></div>
 <script src="script.js">
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```